# How can I check if a doc exists in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I check if an id it's inside my firebase collection?
I need to check if item.id it's inside the collection "favorites" that contains multiple ids.

I need to assign to a value true if it's inside or false if there is not a value with the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to "check" if a document exists inside a collection without actually fetching it. When you attempt to `get` the document, it returns a `doc` - with a `exists` variable.

So you can check if a document exists or not like this (using Promises):

```
const doesDocExist = (docID) => {
    return firestore().collection("cities").doc(docID).get().then((doc) => {
         return doc.exists
    })
}


//Call the function to check if doc exists:
let doesSanFranciscoExist = await doesDocExist("SF")
```

Note that in the above function, you are attempting to fetch the document with the ID.

Alternatively, if you want to check the existence of multiple documents with just one read, you can maintain a list of document ids elsewhere in your database using Cloud Functions.

[Get a document in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: I checked doc.exists value in console log and it correctly assume true or false based on the id, but I still can't use that boolean outside the function, I tried to do an if like this but it always act as true even if in console log appears false:  <View>
          {doesDocExist() ? (
            <Text>true</Text>
          ) : (
            <Text>false</Text>

          )}
        </View>

Comment: I have added how you can use the function - the function returns a Promise, since it's fetching the document from the database. So you need to wait for the Promise to resolve. In your React code, you can add a state variable called `loading` along with another state variable called `docExists`. When the Promise resolves, you can update both state variables.